# Why is pass by value and pass by rvalue overload c++ function call ambiguous?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue

If I have,

```
void foo(Bar c);
void foo(Bar&& c);

foo(Bar());
```

why is the call to 'foo' is ambiguous?
Isn't Bar() in the foo argument clearly an rValue?

Comment: Duplicated to: [Method overloading with move semantic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38847321/514235)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binding to a reference is an "exact match", as is binding to a non-reference, so both overloads are equally good.

In Standardese, this is 13.3.3.1.4 ("Reference binding", [over.ics.ref]):

> When a parameter of reference type binds directly (8.5.3) to an argument expression, the implicit conversion sequence is the identity conversion [...]