# Method overloading with move semantic

Tags: c++, move-semantics, overloading

When I try to overload method with one which uses rvalue reference as a parameter i get an error:

> error: call of overloaded 'Test(std::unique_ptr)' is ambiguous
>   Test t(std::unique_ptr(new int(1)));

code:

```
class Test {
public:
    Test(std::unique_ptr<int> val)
        : v_(std::move(val)) {
        std::cout << "Ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    Test(std::unique_ptr<int>&& val)
        : v_(std::move(val)) {
        std::cout << "Move Ctor" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<int> v_;
};

int main()
{
    Test t(std::move(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(1))));
    return 0;
}
```

Like a compiler, I'm quite confused. In fact, compiler can call fucntion which receive rvalue reference or it can call unique_ptr constructor with rvalue reference and call first method. Why don't it just choise former?

Comment: Do you really need both these constructors? They do the same thing

Comment: Code just for academical use

Comment: Good question. The compilation fails even with `Test t(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(1)));`. @alexeykuzmin0, the problem is, why the compilation **should fail**?

Comment: The normal way to do this is to make one `T &&` overload and a `const T&` overload, but for `unique_ptr` it doesn't actually make sense.

Comment: By the way, the `std::move` you used doesn't actually do anything because it is already a temporary.